# Fragment not showing on actionBar tab select after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I can't get fragments to work properly with ActionBar - when I change tab the fragment switches properly. But when I rotate the phone, then remembered fragment shows correctly (depending on what was selected) but I can't switch to the other tab. There is no error, nothing, and I don't know how to check what is wrong

```
MapHandlerFragment mMapHandler;
VehiclesFragment mVehiclesFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    mMapHandler = new MapHandlerFragment();
    mVehiclesFragment = new VehiclesFragment();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        fm.beginTransaction()
             .add(android.R.id.content, mVehiclesFragment)
             .add(android.R.id.content, mMapHandler)
             .commit();

    } else {

        fm.beginTransaction()
        .hide(mMapHandler)
        .hide(mVehiclesFragment)
        .commit();
    }

    Tab vehiclesTab = ab.newTab().setText("Pojazdy").setTag(FRAGMENT_VEHICLES)
            .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mVehiclesFragment));
    ab.addTab(vehiclesTab);
    Tab mapTab = ab.newTab().setText("Mapa").setTag(FRAGMENT_MAP)
            .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mMapHandler));
    ab.addTab(mapTab);  

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {            
        ab.selectTab(mapTab); 
    } else {
        String selected = savedInstanceState.getString(SELECTED_TAB);
        if (selected == FRAGMENT_VEHICLES) {
            ab.selectTab(vehiclesTab);
        } else if (selected == FRAGMENT_MAP) {
            ab.selectTab(mapTab);
        }           
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(SELECTED_TAB, mSelectedTab);
}

protected class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.show(fragment);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.hide(fragment);
    }
}
```

}

I know I don't add the fragments when `savedInstanceState` is not `null`, but if this would be the case, why does the selected fragment show properly? Also, when I add the fragments, they overlay each other...

Comment: did you check to see if your `onTabReselected` is getting called which I bet it is since there is nothing in there to handle it

Comment: @tyczj Yes it is called, but what should I put there then?

Comment: do whatever you want the application to do when the tab is re-seleted

Answer (score 0):

Its not doing anything because `onTabReselected` is getting called, you can handle it however you want but that is why nothing is happening when you select the tab

Comment: I don't think I understand.. I tried to show desired fragment in `onTabReselected` and it didn't work, I don't know what else could I do.
What should I put there so that fragments would show properly after orientation change?

Comment: you could remove the fragment then add it back on again so you dont have then stacked like you were saying